# Is it necessary to close the connection of sqlite

Tags: xamarin, android-sqlite

I have read in many tutorial that it is not necessary to close the connection in xamarin sqlite because it is not like the connection in **ADO.NET**, it is like DbContext in **Entityframework** but in some tutorials it is said that it is necessary to close the connection

> Here is the xamarin code

```
private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;

public ExperiencePage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISqLiteDb>().GetConnection();
}
```

is it necessary to close the connection or not ?

Comment: For thread safety, it is recommended to close the database after each use.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not necessary to close the connection but how it’s a IDisposable object  you should Dispose it or use using statement.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {
         // some code here
     }
```